# Magento 1.6.2.0 Blank Page

Tags: php, magento, error-handling

Trying to make a Magento System work on my local host - before that is was running on a webserver.

The problem is I don´t get any errors. I would be so happy If I could just see one little php exception or anything at all. The backend works perfectly fine, just the frontend is messed up.

**Here is what I did so far:**

Turned off Compilation in the backend

Deletend /var/cache multiple times

Turned off all the community plugins

used this in my index.php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

And also set

```
$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;
```

I echod $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] and $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] - they semm to be empty.

I deleted all my sessions as well and obviously change my secure and unsecure baseURL to my localhost (otherwise my backend wouldn´t work)

My log files in /var/log are empty - at least the system.log. The exception.log never existed. I created it in the hope it would write something in it then, but no chance. Empty after all.

Any ideas? I am completly clueless at this point. Have read a ton of SOF and other forum posts...

Comment: I think some frontend module breaking, please check server log.

Comment: /var/log/apache2/

There is no log file and in my Xampp/log/php_error.log is nothing too

Comment: Finally you have to traverse logging from index.php to front controller action. And check where code breaks.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: If you aware of magento then you know request flow. So add echo exit or add some log to check which point breaking the code.

Comment: If I was aware of Magento, would I ask questions here?

Comment: In your console in blank page you can find http error status like 404, 403, 500, etc

Comment: Magento CE or EE ?

Comment: The Code is 200

Edition is CE